Stuck on a scene of characters going from one location to another
So the context is that two characters have to go from Country A to Country B. They have to travel through various airports and take a cab in order to reach Country B. The main story starts after they reach the destination and start exploring. Nothing of significance happens in between.
Now, I did read the Transitioning from one setting or location to another
post for reference, but can it be applied to characters moving between countries which are far apart? The intention is already there, and I can have the characters stop at the entrance of the airport, and then open the next scene with them already at the destination but... that big of a transition feels a little too abrupt.
If I skip the travel part and transition too fast, I risk ruining the pacing, but if I don't skip the travel part, I risk making the transition too boring.
Another thing that I should mention is that the whole story is from First person POV and in present tense. And the POV changes at times from character to character (Roughly there are only 3-4 characters that take on the POV)
I have been contemplating this scene since two months, and am at my wits end. I have tried various things:

Have the characters roam the airports and try out
different food stalls and stores, but nothing changes in that scene, making it
boring, and kind of becomes repetitive for each airport.
Have the POV change frequently so that it doesn't get boring,
but that would make things too confusing.
Add something new that wasn't planned to be in the story, for
the sole purpose of making the scene interesting, but then it could
potentially end up making the story needlessly complex.
Have the characters sleep for the journey, but again, it just
ramps up the pacing.
Make them break the fourth wall, and tell the reader that the
journey is going to be boring so the writer will be skipping that,
and the character will see the readers again in the next chapter, but
this still makes the pacing too fast, and doesn't fit too well with the tone of the story.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.


You are creating a problem in your mind where there isn't one.
It is a common convention in narratives — plays, novels, comics, movies — to skip events that are irrelevant to the story. Readers are used to this and won't find this irritating in the least.
A story is not narrating everything that happened. A story is narrating everything that is relevant to killing the dragon or solving the murder mystery or whatever your story is about.
If nothing relevant happens during the journey, skip it (as the comic above does) or summarize it briefly:

After an exhausting twelve hour flight our heroes stepped out of the airport into the smothering heat of late summer Bangkok.


Generally, if your scene(s) doesn't add anything important or meaningful to the story, then it shouldn't be in the story. If your travel and airport sequence or scenes aren't filled with important interactions/events/thoughts/dialogue, what is the purpose of including it?
You say yourself, that the (main) story doesn't really begin before they arrive at the destination and begin exploring. I'd say you have the following actual options:
1: Skip it, if only to have the characters briefly go over/revisit parts of the journey to talk about 'how long' or 'how hard' it was, or how it, strangely, didn't trigger that one character's fear of flying this time.
2: Show parts of the journey. The only reason I see for including part of the journey is to provide insights into the characters and their plans:

What are they like individually?
What is their relation to each other?
Why are they going on the trip?
What are their hopes for the trip?
What are their worries?

Whether you choose 1 or 2, the first few pages we read should give us an idea of who the characters are, and what the 'normal' of their lives are. That way, we better understand what the trip represents and could entail of importance for them.
One way to do this with version 1 could be the following:

Character A: "God, I hope they have separate rooms for those separate
beds in that motel."


Character B: "Jesus christ, will you shut up
about the rooms already. You've talked about it non-stop the entire
way here."


Character A: "First of all, that's a lie, 'cus you've
slept like a damn baby through both flights. Second of all, it's easy
for you to not care about the rooms - You're not the one being kept
awake by the freakin' ork-like snoring of your man-child friend."

Of course, this doesn't tell us that much about the characters, but it does tell us something that we do not need to read scenes about the characters on the plane for. The same could be done for numerous other important and less important talking points that lets us get to know the characters before following their story during the trip.
